# AngularJS $resource object doesn't provide an idempotent update method?

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I've really be trying to wrap my head around this as much as possible, but having a very difficult time doing so.  Maybe I'm missing the obvious.

Given a typical REST API (with an idempotent update method and a create method):

```
http://www.domain.com/api/clients           GET     // returns all clients
http://www.domain.com/api/clients           POST    // create a new  client
http://www.domain.com/api/clients/:id       GET     // returns single client
http://www.domain.com/api/clients/:id       PUT     // updates a single client - idempotent
http://www.domain.com/api/clients/:id       DELETE  // delete single client
```

If I create a standard resource with the following URL:

```
Client = $resource("http://www.domain.com/api/clients/:id")
```

Then I automatically get (where Client is the $resource and client is the returned entity):

```
Client.get()
Client.query()
Client.save()
client.$save()
client.$remove/delete()
```

The problem I have is by default there is no `PUT` method to save (typically used to identify idempotent updates).

Am I misunderstanding something or is this a deficiency in Angular's API?  I would have expected the `$save()` to use a `PUT` and not a `POST`.  The way it is currently structured, I have to create my own `$update()` method definition and then rely on the developer not to accidentally use the `$save()` method.

Am I structuring my API incorrectly?  Should the REST API be structured differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply specify the method in your resource like :

```
app.factory('someFactory', ['$resource', function($resource) {
  return $resource('/api/:id', {
    id: '@id'
  }, {
  update: {
    method: 'PUT'
  },
  get: {
    method: 'GET'
  }
 });
}]);
```

but I totally agree with $save being an odd verb for create and not update. [This guy](http://kirkbushell.me/angular-js-using-ng-resource-in-a-more-restful-manner/) does too and it looks like he made a way to dual purpose the save by simply extending the object and checking for an id.

Comment: Yes - I am fully aware of that.  However, that would mean that I need to do it for every resource which follows this pattern.  It also means that I have a `$save()` method which is invalid (but I cannot eliminate).  So I can't help but wonder if/why AngularJS doesn't already do this by default.  Since AngularJS is supposed to work with best practices, etc, it makes me further wonder if my REST design should be re-examined to be more flexible/compatible/etc.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking of something along the same lines, but am just very surprised that it isn't part of Angular already by default.  Can you edit your answer and add your comment to it for anyone looking at this in the future?